# @html razor radio buttons mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

here's my viewmodel

```
public class UserResponseModel
    {
        public string QuestionId { get; set;} 

        public string QuestionText { get; set; }

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }


    }
```

so, for checkboxes this works beautifully

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.UserResponses.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked)
```

but for radio buttons this does not

```
 for (var i = 0; i < Model.UserResponses.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked, new { Name = "grp1" })
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionText)
```

when i submit the form then IsChecked is always false - why - what am i missing - as I mentioned for checkboxes it works just fine. I did look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987360/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-show-grouped-radio-buttons-for-two-model-fields) but i'm not sure why radiobuttons require extra properties in the view model to hold the correct answer when checkboxes work transparently.

Edit: my question model is now as so

```
public class QuestionModel
    {
        public string WhichQuestion { get; set; }

        public int PointsObtained { get; set; }

        public bool CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

        private List<UserResponseModel> _userResponse;
        public List<UserResponseModel> UserResponses 
        {
            get { return _userResponse ?? (_userResponse = new List<UserResponseModel>()); }
            set { _userResponse = value; }
        }
    }
```

notice i have just added public bool CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

and in my view here's the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.UserResponses.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CorrectAnswer)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked, Model.CorrectAnswer, new { Name = "grp1" })
```

EDIT 2:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedAnswerId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked,    Model.SelectedAnswerId, new { Name = "grp1" })
```

EDIT3:

```
public class QuestionModel
    {
        public string WhichQuestion { get; set; }

        public int PointsObtained { get; set; }



        private List<UserResponseModel> _userResponse;
        public List<UserResponseModel> UserResponses 
        {
            get { return _userResponse ?? (_userResponse = new List<UserResponseModel>()); }
            set { _userResponse = value; }
        }
    }

public class UserResponseModel
    {
        public string QuestionId { get; set;} 

        public string QuestionText { get; set; }



        public string SelectedQuestionId { get; set; }

    }
```

finally, my view

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.UserResponses.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[i].QuestionId, new { Name = "grp1" })
                    @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].IsChecked)*@
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].QuestionText)
```

EDIT4:so finally I'm getting some where 
this works!!!

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
```

I can now see the selectedquestionid populated in my httppost method but if I do this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[i].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[i].QuestionId, new {Name="grp"})
```

then though i am able to select only one radiobutton  the selectedquestionid *is* null on httppost - wierd

Comment: This may help you http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radio buttons are not checkboxes. Radio buttons are grouped. This means that you should have a single property on your view model to hold the selected radio button value (as shown in the [`answer you linked to`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987510/29407)). With check boxes you could have multiple checkboxes selected, that's thy you are binding them to a collection of boolean values in your view model. Radio buttons on the other hand have only one possible selected value because they are mutually exclusive. That's why they should all be bound to a single property on your view model that will hold the selected radio button value.

So in your example of questions and answers, you have a question view model that will contain the question id and text as well as a list of possible answers. Each answer will be represented by an id and text. Your question view model will also have an answer property that will hold the selected answer radio button from the user. It is this property that you are going to bind all your radio button to. But with a different value.

Comment: I've done some thing similar to the answer for the question I linked to, how do i get to store the id in the CorrectAnswer that belongs to the questionmodel

Comment: You simply add a property `SelectedAnswerId` to your view model. Then you bind all your radio buttons to this property. The correct answer to a given question should not be part of your view model. That's an information that should live only inside your database and domain models. When the user submits the form, you're gonna get the `SelectedAnswerId` property value on your view model as well as the question id. Now you're gonna check in your database whether this is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: "the correct answer..." - of course - I get that - so the SelectedAnswerId will be in the QuestionModel but how do I bind it to the radio buttons - if you could show me some code i would really appreciate it

Comment: see my Edit2 - is that the way to go

Comment: No, that's not the correct way. You should bind your radio button to the `SelectedAnswerId` property that you should define on your view model: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedAnswerId, Model[i].ANswerId)`. Please read more carefully the linked answer.

Comment: please see my edit3 - what am i missing - the SelectedAnswerId does not contain the question id when I select a given radio button - I've tried this now for the past 3 hours and any help would be much apprciated.