# radiobuttonfor grouping razor mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The selected values are not getting posted back when I group my radio buttons,

So, with this the SelectedQuestionId *is* blank

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">

                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].QuestionId)
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[0].QuestionId, new { Name ="selectone"})
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].QuestionText)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].QuestionText)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].InputType)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].Points)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].Points)</span>&nbsp;@Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].Points, new { @class = "text-muted" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].QuestionId)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[1].QuestionId, new { Name = "selectone"})
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].QuestionText)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].QuestionText)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].InputType)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].Points)




                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].Points)</span>&nbsp;@Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].Points, new { @class = "text-muted" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

But the moment i remove the grouping from the radiobuttonfor then all works well, and the SelectedQuestionId is populated with questionid. So, replacing the RadioButtonFor above with these allow the SelectedQuestionId to be populated when the form is posted. 
The code above is based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987360/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-show-grouped-radio-buttons-for-two-model-fields) and though I have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939325/html-razor-radio-buttons-mvc5) - this question is entirely separate.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[0].QuestionId)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[1].QuestionId)
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution to this rather intractable problem.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[0].QuestionId)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[1].QuestionId)
```

with the code above each radiobutton had a unique name during the deserialization process the SelectedQuestionId property would be populated for a given item if it was selected as one would expect. However, for the radiobutton to belong to a group they would need to have the same name attribute and since this was not the case in the above scenario one could select both the radio buttons. Which also meant that with multiple radiobuttons being selcted selectedId property for all the selected radio buttons would be populated with their respective QuestionId.

To get around this one could always write code as so,

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[0].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[0].QuestionId, new { Name = "selectone"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UserResponses[1].SelectedQuestionId, Model.UserResponses[1].QuestionId, new { Name = "selectone"})
```

And, now one gets the ability to select only one radiobutton but then during the deserialization process in the HttpPost method the SelectedQuestionId property for each item in the collection would be null. Obviously, the name of the radiobuttons were now "selectone" and so in the key/value pairing for SelectedQuestionId the value would not be getting populated, in other words the SelectedQuestionId would always be null even for the radio button that was selected.

So, the solution was the following:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedId, Model.UserResponses[i].QuestionId)
```

x.SelectedId lies in the ParentModel, and gets populated with the QuestionId of the question that is selected and since both the radio button share the same name they therefore belong to the same group and hence only one of the radio buttons can be selected.